# Unable to create selectize dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am trying to create the selectize dropdown but it doesn't seem to work and doesn't throw any error in console at all.
Here's the JS:

```
var selectizeVals=[
 { code:"f", name:"foo"},
 { code:"b", name:"bar"}
];

$('#demo-selectize').selectize({
    labelField: 'name',
    valueField: 'name',
    searchField: 'name',
    options: selectizeVals,
    render: {
    item: function(item, escape) {
        return "<div>" + escape(item.name) + "</div>";
    },
    option: function(item, escape) {
        return "<div>" + escape(item.name) + "</div>";
    }
},
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <select id="demo-selectize" name="demo-selectize" placeholder="Select an item">
  </select>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

I have included the [jQuery.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js), [selectize.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selectize/selectize.js/master/dist/js/standalone/selectize.js) and default selectize.css in my code in the head tag. The values don't get appended in the select drop down - only an empty select tag renders on the html. What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems to be Working here : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/xL5hss2v/

Comment: Only sees to be working for FF. I was working in Chrome - even disabled all my extensions and it isn't working in Chrome, Chrome Canary or even Edge.